# Problem uploading my sketch onto my arduino. Arduino 1.8.13, Linux Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: uploading, linux, ubuntu

This is my log, honestly no idea what the problem is here, tried updating java, didnt work.

```
Sketch uses 11216 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Global variables use 2384 bytes (7%) of dynamic memory, leaving 30384 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 32768 bytes.
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2055)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port '/dev/ttyACM0'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - /dev/ttyACM0; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Permission denied.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:170)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: look at the second `caused by` line

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#please-read

Comment: Is your user in the dailout group? That is required for you to use the serial devices. And after you added the group to your user, you need to relogon to get thar change active

Comment: How do i find out if i am in the dailout group

Comment: I added my user using  [ $ sudo adduser "user" dialout  ] and it worked thank you